# Проблема с авторизацией

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема в том, что  код проверяет только логин с одной страницы, а мне надо что-бы он проверял логин еще с другой.
     В общем как сделать этот код рабочим

```
    $res_login = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM `datacenter` WHERE `login` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']).'"' );
     $res_login1 = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM `datacenter` WHERE `login` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login']).'"' );
    if (mysql_num_rows($res_login) != 1 or mysql_num_rows($res_login1) != 1){
echo '<script>location.replace("nologin.php");</script>'; exit;
}
   else {.....
..........
```

Comment: POST запрос отправлять с помощью AJAX(как вариант)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых если тебе нужна вся информация о пользователе - намного целесообразнее во время авторизации записать всю информацию прямо в сессию и не тревожить по чем зря БД.

т.е. во время проверки авторизации делаешь как-то так:

```
session_start(); // куда-же без нее :)
//   обрабатываем данные формы авторизации
if( !empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ) {

   //   подключение к БД

   // как у тебя хранится пароль я не в курсе
   // предположу что в md5 hash
   // вообщем-то не суть, надо будет - поправишь

   $login = '"' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']) . '"';
   $password = '"' . md5($_POST['password']) . '"';

   // собственно делаем запрос и сразу-же обрабатываем
   $userData = mysql_fetch_assoc(
       mysql_query('SELECT * FROM your_users_table WHERE login=' . $login .
               ' AND password=' . $passsoword
       )
   );

   // если введенные пользователем данные верны - то у нас есть массив с инфой о юзере
   // т.е. пользователя надо авторизовать
   if( $userData ) { // если массив данных не пустой
       //  положим всю инфу о юзере в сессию
       foreach($userData as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
       }
       // ну и дальше код...
   }
   else {
        // код если пользователь ввел фигню...
   }
}
```

Это как вариант, так сказать попытка прочесть мысли...

Если же все-таки необходимо именно так как ты написал, то просто вначале любого скрипта

```
session_start();
//  подключение к БД
if(!empty($_SESSION['login'])) {  // если пользователь авториован
   $userData = mysql_fetch_assoc(
       mysql_query('SELECT * FROM your_users_table WHERE login=' . $_SESSION['login']
       )
   );
   foreach($userData as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
   }
}
```

Думаю в любом случае что-то да подойдет, если я правильно понял вопрос, а то они у тебя все какие-то размытые :)